# Does this graph join like operation have a known name? Any special algebraic property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, terminology, binary-operations, algebraic-graph-theory

I am defining a graph operation $\pmb\nabla$ in the following.

> The notation $\pmb\nabla$ is a modified form of graph join operation, and defined as follows. Consider two graphs $G$ and $H$, then
> $G\pmb\nabla H=\langle V(G)\cup V(H), E(G)\cup E(H)\cup \lbrace uv: u\in V(G), v\in V(H);~u\notin V(H), v\notin V(G) \rbrace\rangle.$

This definition is closely related to graph join operation with the difference being a restriction that $u\notin V(H), v\notin V(G)$. Note that this operation is closed and associative.

Does this operation have a name? Any important algebraic properties of this operation?

Comment: The main difference between this operation and graph join is that graph join is a true graph-theoretic operation (it respects graph isomorphism - if $G \cong G'$ and $H \cong H'$, then $G+H \cong G' +H'$) and your operation isn't: it depends on the "vertex labeling" of $G$ and $H$ to decide which vertices of $G$ "are also" vertices of $H$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ok. That is also noted......

Comment: It seems like there is only a purpose to define something like this if you are using it for something; so I would turn the question around: Is there a reason you think this operation is interesting? Have you found it to have any special properties?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I am also looking for its special algebraic properties. I hope it may be useful in computer networking problems like road and internet traffic congestion like situations. Hopefully it can be used to suggest  virtual paths in finding optimal paths, etc.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @gete That is really a very generic description of its "usefulness". Why is this particular operation useful for these types of problems? Is there something that led you to consider this particularly? I seems like you just have $(G \cup H) \cup ((G \setminus (G \cap H)) + (H \setminus (G \cap H)))$. Probably if there is no real motivation for this, no one has bothered to give it a special name.

Comment: @MorganRodgers A trivial example: Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ represent groups of $m$ and $n$ persons, respectively. If every pair of persons in the respective groups have shaken their hands exactly once.  How many hand shakes will be their among all the persons of $G_1$ and $G_2$ combined if every pair of persons has exactly once handshake?                                                                                                                Note:  Consider each person as a node or vertex and a handshake as an edge. The required hand shakes= |E(G_1\pmb\nabla G_2)|

Comment: @gete I think your formulas did not appear correctly, I can't guess what they are supposed to be. But this does not make sense, how are you interpreting $G_{1}$ as a graph here? You define $G_{1}$ as a group of $m$ persons (fine, so a set of $m$ vertices), are you thinking of it as the empty graph on these vertices? And if so, your strange pseudo-join operation would suggest that there are no edges between pairs of vertices in $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$, which does not seem to be what you want.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for your comments. Yes I need a correction in language. $G_1$ and $G_2$ are networks of $m$ and $n$ persons, respectively. Two persons are connected by an edge if and only if they have shaken hands. According to the question, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are complete graphs. Hence the vertices in $G_1\cap G_2$ are complete sub graphs. Our operation takes care that no repetition of edges of $G_1\cap G_2$ in $G_1\pmb\nabla G_2$. However, I would be glad to hear if we could discuss in more details. In that case, you may feel free to contact at gete.umbrey@rgu.ac.in